# Java IO Exception - Stream Closed

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a set of facebook user id's i collected with my PHP based application .

I saved it as a txt file and trying to get the Real names of people . I am using java for this.

Normally http://graph.facebook.com/userid will give Json response with name and other info.

```
while((temp = br.readLine())!=null){                
    url = new URL("http://graph.facebook.com/"+temp);
    urlcon = url.openConnection();
    bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlcon.getInputStream()));
    response = bf.readLine();
    Map jsonData=parser.parseJson(response);
    value=(String)jsonData.get("name");
    System.out.println(value);
}
```

I will get some output untill i start getting an Exception .

```
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
```

some one told me to set useragent so i tried

```
System.setProperty("http.agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-US; rv:1.4b) Gecko/20030516 Mozilla Firebird/0.6");
```

This doesn't seem to work . What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: You should probably do a couple of things: read more than just the first line, and ***CLOSE*** the urlcon. At the moment you are leaving a lot of open sockets to facebook

Answer (score 0):

Since you aren't closing the stream, that means somebody else is.  Generally, sockets only stay open for a small amount of time before the server closes them.  You may want to refactor your code so that every time you open a URL connection, you read all the data into some kind of data structure, close the connection, then perform operations on the data.  You could do something like:

```
List<String> data; //some data structure you've initialized beforehand.
String temp;
while ((temp = bf.readLine()) != null) {
    data.add(temp);
}
bf.close();
//do stuff with the data...
```